# Selfhosted Azure DevOps Agents volume mapping

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am getting the following error when running a self hosted (docker) build agent in K8s when executing a containerised task. I have followed the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops).

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/__a/externals/node/bin/node": stat /__a/externals/node/bin/node: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I think the root cause is that the volume mapping in the inner container is referencing the host filesystem. If that is the case, the question is - What needs to be done to get the agent to reference the outer container so that the agent will work for containerised jobs.