# Testcontainers with volume mounts on custom Azure DevOps build agent running in Docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, testcontainers

I am having trouble running some integration tests that use Testcontainers on a self-managed custom Azure DevOps agent that is already running in Docker.

The host is an Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Machine on Azure. It has Docker installed and there are 2 docker images running, one for our Java-based builds and one for the Angular-based builds. Inside the Java-based one, we run Maven with Testcontainers.

The Docker image that is created for the build agent itself, is based on the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux. It runs Ubuntu 18.04, has a `WORKDIR /azp` and `ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]`.

The build agent is started manually on the host via:

```
docker run -d --name build-agent-java-1 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -e AZP_URL=https://dev.azure.com/my-organisation \
  -e AZP_TOKEN=<mytoken> \
  -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=agent-1 \ 
  custombuildagentcr.azurecr.io/ubuntu1804-java11
```

The `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` is added following the [Testcontainers documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/)

This works for some Testcontainers tests, but not for others. More specially, it does not work for a test where the container started by testcontainers needs access to the compiled class files (which are present on the build agent docker).

After searching through a lot of other questions, I believe the problem is that the "inner docker" cannot "see" the files on the "outer docker" (the build agent). See [Docker volume mounts not working in Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172042/docker-volume-mounts-not-working-in-azure-devops-pipeline) and [Selfhosted Azure DevOps Agents volume mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426392/selfhosted-azure-devops-agents-volume-mapping)

However, it is not clear to me how to apply this exactly.

I tried to add `-v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD` when starting the build agent Docker (Because the Testcontainer documentation indicates this). However, this makes the image fail to start as `./start.sh` as ENTRYPOINT no longer can be resolved as the WORKDIR is changed.

I also tried to change the ENTRYPOINT to use an absolute path `/azp/start.sh` (and also do a `cd /azp` inside that `start.sh` file), but that still does not work.

If I check the mounts that are available, it returns this:

```
devops-agent-host-user@shared-devops-agent-host:~$ docker inspect build-agent-java-1 | jq '.[0].Mounts'
[
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/devops-agent-host-user",
    "Destination": "/home/devops-agent-host-user",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
    "Destination": "/var/run/docker.sock",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
]
```

Azure itself has [Mounting volumes using Docker within a Docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#mounting-volumes-using-docker-within-a-docker-container), but I unfortunately fail to understand how to apply this to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a generic solution, but the problem I had went away for me with [testcontainers-keycloak](https://github.com/dasniko/testcontainers-keycloak) 1.9.0 as it no longer uses a bind mount, but copies the class files into the container (See https://github.com/dasniko/testcontainers-keycloak/issues/44).